# Click on OK message in 'Remote Desktop Connection' Banner using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automate the steps below using powershell. I'm able to perform Step1

## Step1: Open the RDP Connection with the user credentials.

## Step2: Click on OK Windows Banner.

I'm not able to perform Step2 in powershell. Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

[image]

Comment: It's designed so you have to click it.. without something like AHK, you can't automate that.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 : Looks like you didn't get the question and objective. I have answered this question. Appreciated if you don't down vote in such scenarios.

Comment: In the future I'd recommend using the Q&A option so it's obvious what you're doing because as it stands you have a bad question with nothing that can actually be helped.

Comment: I am not gonna downvote but you will need to use UI automation to achieve this. UI automation is almost always inconsistent when dealing with RDP because of different OS, resolution etc. On top of it, not every machine will always provide an OK button in which case, it will directly take you to the desktop. And now you can imagine, it can potentially be dangerous to click unintentionally on the screen.

Comment: Yes, I didn't used UI Automation tool, But Powershell has the potential to perform some Windows actions using its native events. Thats what i used and was able to perform the mouse action to Click on OK button( Refer to the code used  ). I posted this for Powershell because i have used that lang to connect to RDP session and want to complete Step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with the below code:

Step#1 is done as mentioned in the below URL: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b

Step#2: Done with the below code.

```
[system.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("####TITLE OF THE WINDOW####") | out-null

# Set the exactly position of cursor in some iexplore hyperlink between the (open parenthesis) below: 
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(790,675)
Click-MouseButton


function Click-MouseButton
{
    $signature=@' 
      [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);
'@ 

    $SendMouseClick = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature -name "Win32MouseEventNew" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru 

        $SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        $SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I need to execute the same scenario, can you share the complete script, because it's not working for me.

Comment: I have shared the Script in this post ( Step#2) , U can use that. I would recommend to resize the Window and than use it.